# PHP returning unusual data in different applications

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I have an IOS App that querys MYSQL database but when i run the query in the browser window using this url - http://hugt.co.uk/checkuserverification.php?Email=tp_redo_c@hotmail.com&Password=ULLAFI01, this seems to work and responds with a 'loggedin' but when i use IOS i get a different response from the server. The response i get when running IOS i get 'not registered/n'

Why do i get different responses from using two different applications to run the script?

Here is my PHP Script:

```
<?php

        include "connect.php";


        $email = $_GET["Email"];
        $password = $_GET["Password"];

        $verificationCode = null;
        if(isset($_GET['Verification'])){

            $verificationCode = $_GET["Verification"];
        }

        $hasBeenVerified = 0;
        $qryCheck = "SELECT U_Verified, U_ID FROM U_User WHERE U_Email = '$email' AND U_Password = '$password'";
        $resultCheck = mysqli_query($conn, $qryCheck);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultCheck);

        if($num_rows > 0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultCheck);
            $hasBeenVerified = $row[0]; 
            if($hasBeenVerified == 1){

                echo 'loggedin';

            }else{

                if($verificationCode != null){

                    $qryCheck2 = "SELECT U_VerificationCode, U_ID FROM U_User WHERE U_Email = '$email' AND U_Password = '$password'";
                    $resultCheck2 = mysqli_query($conn, $qryCheck2);
                    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultCheck2);
                    if($row2[0] == $verificationCode){
                        $updateRecordVerified = 'UPDATE U_User SET U_Verified = true WHERE U_Email = "$email"';
                        $resultCheck3 = mysqli_query($conn, $updateRecordVerified);
                        if($resultCheck3){
                            echo $row2[1];
                        }else{
                            echo 'server error';
                        }                                                   
                    }else{
                        echo 'invalid verification';
                    }

                }else{
                    //echo 'hhh' . $row[0];
                    echo 'no verification';

                }


            }       


        }else{
            echo 'not registered';
        }
    ?>
```

This is my IOS PHP Script Call:

```
        -(NSString*)setupPhpCall:(NSString*)requestString :(NSString*)sciptPage{

        NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

        // Create your request string with parameter name as defined in PHP file
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.hugt.co.uk/%@", sciptPage]]];
        // set Request Type
        [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
        // Set content-type
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
        // Set Request Body
        [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
        // Now send a request and get Response

        NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&urlResponse error: &error];
        // Log Response
        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
        return response;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer is that you are testing for "$_GET" variables in the PHP script and you are sending the request via POST in the IOS app.

```
$email = $_GET["Email"];
$password = $_GET["Password"];

// set Request Type
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
```

Perhaps you want to switch that to $_POST or use $_REQUEST to catch both.

Comment: Thanks,that worked using $_REQUEST, but i still have a problem that the response still appends '/n' this is not needed, how would i get rid of the '/n' after the response data

Comment: Try adding an `exit()` after you `echo` your response (or at the end of the script). You can also remove the closing `?>` to ensure that there will be no newline characters emitted back in the request.

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend you to use ASIHTTPRequest for sending request on server and use your function as**

```
-(void)setupPhpCall:(NSString*)username  Passward:(NSString*)password
{
 NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://hugt.co.uk/checkuserverification.php?"];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setPostValue:username forKey:@“Email”];
        [request setPostValue:password forKey:@“Password”];
        [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
        [request startSynchronous];
}

-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
 NSError *error;
 if(!error)
 {
  NSString *receivedString = [request responseString];
  NSLog(@“Response = %@", receivedString);
 }
}
```

output : loggedin